# Getting error in my rails application of editing a list of books ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BooksController#edit Couldn't find Book with id=id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ROR and got stuck here .I need help.Please help in detecting the error which has occured in my implemetation of editing function in an application containing list of books.

Following is my code in index.html.erb :

```
<div id="a1">
<% @books.each do |book| %>

  <div class="book">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <p class="rank-this-week"> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <p class="title"> <%= book.title %> </p>
        <p class="author"> by <%= book.author %>  </p>
        <p class="publisher"> <%= book.publisher %> </p>
        <p class="description"> <%= book.description %> </p>
        <%= link_to 'See all Editorial Reviews', book %>
        <%= id = book.id %>
        <!--<%= link_to 'Edit Book', "books/1/edit" %>-->
        <a href="books/id/edit">Edit Book</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <p class="weeks-on-list"> <%= book.weeks_on_list %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<!--<%= link_to 'New Book', "books/new" %> -->
<a href="books/new">New Book</a>



</div>
```

Following is my code of books controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

    def index
    Rails.logger.info "Books Path: #{books_path}\nBooks URL: #{books_url}\nBook Path: #{book_path(1)}\nBook URL: #{book_url(1)}\nEdit Book Path: #{edit_book_path(1)}\nEdit Book URL: #{edit_book_url(1)}}"
    @books = Book.all

    end

  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

    def show
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      @reviews = @book.reviews
   end

   def create
    b = Book.new(params[:book])
    if b.save
      #success
    else
      #failure
    end
    # b = Book.create(params[:book])

    # @book_new= Book.new(books_params) 
    #render 'books'
    redirect_to :action => :index
    # redirect_to books_path
    end

    def edit
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])

   end

    def update
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
         redirect_to :action => 'show' 
      else
         @reviews = Review.find(:all)
         render :action => 'edit'
      end
    end

   # private 
   # def books_params
   # params.require(:book).permit(:title)
   # end

end
```

The error I am getting is :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BooksController#edit

Couldn't find Book with id=id
```

Comment: You need to look at [***resourceful routes***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code looks, replace following lines in `index.html.erb`,

```
<%= id = book.id %>
<!--<%= link_to 'Edit Book', "books/1/edit" %>-->
<a href="books/id/edit">Edit Book</a>
```

with

```
<%= id = book.id %>
<%= link_to 'Edit Book', "books/#{id}/edit" %>
```